# instead of day ago, minutes ago or hours ago I want to scrape the date published in today so date should be of today or date of published day scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Instead of a day ago, minutes ago, or hours ago I want to scrape the date if published today so the date should be of today or the date of published day in scrapy using python.

This the code I try.

```
Published_Date = response.css('time::text').get().replace(",","").replace("Published ","")#Published Jul 30, 2019
if "AGO" in Published_Date:
    Published_Date = date.today() 
else:
    Published_Date =  datetime.strptime(Published_Date, "%b %d %Y").date()
```

URL of the site. https://simpleflying.com/us-carriers-dot-delay-compensation-push/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape the `@datetime` attribute directly from the `<time>` tag and use the `datetime` module to parse the date it was published and the `timedelta` to check how long ago it was published.

```py
import scrapy
import datetime

class DTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dt'
    start_urls = ['https://simpleflying.com/us-carriers-dot-delay-compensation-push/']

    def parse(self, response):
        dt = response.css('span.meta_txt.date').xpath('./time/@datetime').get()
        date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dt[:-1])
        print(date, '|' ,date.day,'|',date.month, '|', date.year) 
        # 2022-10-23 17:10:00 | 23 | 10 | 2022  #<-- output
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        delta = today - date
        print(delta.days)   # 0  <-- output
```

Comment: I got this Error
Published_Date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dt[:-1])
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Then you didn't import it correctly.... you can either fix the import statement or you can remove the first datetime...  obviously the datetime module has an object [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types).  look at how I import it at the top of my example, and then look at how you import it in your own code...